# Is IDisposable.Dispose() called automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will the Garbage Collector call IDisposable.Dispose for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036/will-the-garbage-collector-call-idisposable-dispose-for-me)

I have a Class which has some unmanaged resources. My class implements the `IDisposable` interface and releases the unmanaged resources in the `Dispose()` method. Do I have to call the `Dispose()` method or will it be automatically called somehow? Will the Garbage Collector call it?

Answer (score 81):

`Dispose()` will not be called automatically. If there is a *finalizer* it will be called automatically. Implementing `IDisposable` provides a way for users of your class to release resources early, instead of waiting for the garbage collector.

The preferable way for a client is to use the `using` statement which handles automatic calling of `Dispose()` even if there are exceptions.

A proper implementation of `IDisposable` is:

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
  private bool disposed = false;

  void Dispose() 
  { 
    Dispose(true); 
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if(!disposed)
    {
      if(disposing)
      {
        // Manual release of managed resources.
      }
      // Release unmanaged resources.
      disposed = true;
    }
  }

  ~MyClass() { Dispose(false); }
}
```

If the user of the class calls `Dispose()` the cleanup takes place directly. If the object is catched by the garbage collector, it calls `Dispose(false)` to do the cleanup. Please note that when called from the finalizer (the `~MyClass` method) managed references may be invalid, so only unmanaged resources can be released.

Comment: A late addition: that finalizer is not called immediately when the reference is out-of-scope, but "some time (possibly: much) later" when the GC comes around to it. So: *do not depend on the finalizer for cleanup*

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that Dispose is called automatically if a Finalizer exists (even if the Finalizer does not call the Dispose method). But an explicit Finalizer doesn't automatically call Dispose does it, unless you explicitly code the Finalizer to call Dispose.

Comment: shouldn't "void Dispose()" be "public void Dispose()"? I am getting a compiler error if i omit the public... perhaps something has changed since 2011..
Can i edit your post and fix it?

Answer (score 11):

You *will* have to call this method manually, maybe (assuming that "MyClass" implements "IDisposable") in a construct like

```
using(var myclass = new MyClass())
{
   // do something with myclass
}

// now 'myclass'is Disposed
```

In **C# 8.0**, you can write as below statement:

```
using var myclass=new MyClass();
```

and the "myclass" will be disposed automatically at the end of the scope.

The advantage of the `using` statement (compared to calling Dispose() explicitly) is that `Dispose()` is called no matter how you exit this block: by running past the end, encountering a `return` statement or having an exception thrown.

Answer (score 11):

If you instantiate your object in a `using` statement, Dispose() is called for you when code exits the `using` block

```
using(var myObject = new MyDisposableObject())
{
  blah();
} // Dispose() is called here (or whenever the code exits the block)
```

If you don't use `using`, then it's up to you (the calling code) to dispose of your object by explicitely calling Dispose().

Also, you (the implementor of MyObject) can add support for a finalizer in case your caller doesn't call Dispose(). More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

To make sure the resources are correctly disposed, you need to both implement `IDisposable` and call `Dispose` in the destructor(finalizer).

```
class Foo : IDisposable
{
    private bool m_disposed = false;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!m_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            { 
                //release managed resources
            }
            //release unmanaged resources

            m_disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the `m_` prefix?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I used to `m_` prefix private members a few years ago... now I'm using `_` prefix. `m` stands for `member`.